# Split column SSIS

Tags: ssis, integration

How to split the column by delimiter comma?

I have this value

```
Province/state, Country/Region, Lat,Long
               ,Japan, 36,138
Douglas Country, OR, US,10,15
```

I need to separate as:

```
Douglas Country, OR             US          10         15
                                Japan       36         138
```

4 columns, any suggestion?

Comment: I would suggest adding a C# transformation script component with 4 output columns and handle the splitting within this component.

Comment: Will there ever be more than 4 commas? Since you mention Japan, they have a multi-tier address system so you could have something like `Yoita-otsu 5881-3, Yoita-machi, Nagaoka-shi, Niigata-ken` for [Nagaoka, Niigata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagaoka,_Niigata) as part of an address.